# How to detect device type with Cloud Functions for Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have two apps one is a web app and another one is android. Both share the same authentication database. When a user signs up from the web app, an email I am sending to admin but I should not send an email when a user sign up from the android app. But email is going to admin when a user signs up from the android as well. Is there any ways to detect the android device so that I don't send email from the firebase auth.onCreate function? Thank for the help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It seems you are not giving enough details for the people to be able to help you. Could you clarify your question, for instance by telling more about your authentication mechanism, and the e-mail mechanism you use?

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit information available in Cloud Functions about the platform that triggered its invocation.

If you need such information, you will have to pass it in yourself. How to do that depends on the trigger type of the Cloud Function, but the most universal way to pass information would be to use a Callable Cloud Function and pass the platform information as an additional parameter.